# Drive.revisions.list isn't returning lastModifyingUserName or lastModifyingUser

Tags: google-drive-api

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.revisions.list?fileId=&fields=items(id%252ClastModifyingUser%252ClastModifyingUserName%252Cmd5Checksum%252CmodifiedDate)&_h=5&

We have an a documents list based app which uses the old revisions API to list usernames of who modified a file. It seems with the Drive API and drive.revisions.list, there is no username being returned, so we won't be able to use it to show who changed an older revision.

The lack of our user names is one of our blockers to migrate over to the new API.

Other fields such as the md5sum as missing as well.

Comment: Will be fixed in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Same result reproduced. This issue is reported now.

For now, you can use Files.get() which will return lastModifyingUser of latest change of the whole file, although you cannot view lastModifyingUser for each revision.