# Revisions list and get missing information

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

Using the Google APIs Explorer as well as the official C# library for Google Drive API **v3**, the response is missing most of the [documented fields](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions#resource). I specifically need access to who did the revisions, which should be accessible via `$.lastModifyingUser`.

I've tried this on my domain admin account as well as a service account, so it *shouldn't* be a permission issue, at least not that I can see. What am I doing wrong, if anything?

[List](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list):

```
{
 "kind": "drive#revisionList",
 "revisions": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#revision",
   "id": "1",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
   "modifiedTime": "2016-11-16T18:29:29.527Z"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#revision",
   "id": "14",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
   "modifiedTime": "2016-11-16T18:35:49.184Z"
  },
  ...
```

[Single get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/get):

```
{
 "kind": "drive#revision",
 "id": "134088",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
 "modifiedTime": "2017-05-24T11:48:00.788Z"
}
```

Comment: I found this old question referencing same trouble with the older v2 API, where someone has replied that it's a server-side issue that's been reported, but that was 4 years ago. https://stackoverflow.com/q/18177577/1780502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `fields="*"`, or `fields="permissions(id,lastModifyingUser)"` to your request to instruct Drive to return the full resource. By default, only a minimal set of properties is returned.

Comment: For the record, `*` worked, but comma-separated list did not.

Comment: I believe that there is no default value so the request fails rather than returning a minimal set of properties.

Comment: For me even with the * it does not return the lastModifyingUser information. Is it related with my user's permissions ? Ont he drive I can normally see the activity tab.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to retrieve the "lastModifyingUser" from the revisions API but I was able to retrieve the "lastModifyingUser" from the Files.get fro example:

> ```
>     File foundFile = service.files().get(id)
>             .setSupportsTeamDrives(true)
>             .setFields("parents, webViewLink, properties, lastModifyingUser")
>             .execute();
>
>     System.out.println("Found file is " + foundFile);
>     System.out.println("Parents " + foundFile.getParents());
>     System.out.println("Owners " + foundFile.getOwners());
>     System.out.println("Props " + foundFile.getProperties());
>     System.out.println("Last user " + foundFile.getLastModifyingUser());
> ```