# Google drive API get thumbnail

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to get a thumbnail that google drive creates for the stored pdf files. With this function I am listing all the files:

```
  listFiles: function (folderId, onData, onError) {

    drive.files.list({
        auth: jwtClient,
        q: "'" + folderId + "' in parents"
    }, function (err, res) {
         console.log(res.files)
       }
    });
```

The output of a console log for each file looks like this:

```
{ 
  kind: 'drive#file',
  id: '0BapkdhpPsqtgf01YbEJRRlhuaVUf',
  name: 'file-name.pdf',
  mimeType: 'application/pdf' 
}
```

When I check the google's documentation, it says that metadata of a file should contain all of these properties: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files
and there I found: `contentHints.thumbnail.image` How do I access it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revisions list and get missing information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958371/revisions-list-and-get-missing-information)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958371/revisions-list-and-get-missing-information/44959991#44959991

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the thing is to get the **metadata** of a file I needed to use a `files.get` function, not `files.list`. Another thing is that in the call, field parameter needs to be set. For example:

```
drive.files.get({
    auth: jwtClient,
    fileId: fileId,
    fields : "thumbnailLink"
})
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the fields parameter to change which metadata fields are returned:

```
drive.files.list({
    auth: jwtClient,
    q: "'" + folderId + "' in parents",
    fields: "files(id, name, mimeType, thumbnailLink)"
}, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res.files)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get essential metadata with following api call.
Workaround for python:

```
self.__results = drive_service.files().list(pageSize=10, supportsAllDrives = True, fields = "files(kind, id, name, mimeType, webViewLink, hasThumbnail, thumbnailLink, createdTime, modifiedTime, owners, permissions, iconLink, imageMediaMetadata)").execute()
```

or

```
self.__results = drive_service.files().list(pageSize=10, supportsAllDrives = True, fields = "*").execute()
```

to get complete metadata.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource