# thumbnail of document uploaded in google drive in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I have a file uploading project in which user uploads the document doc or pdf that will be saved in google drive. I want that during uploading I get the thumbnail or can say first page of document as image and save that in database.

this is my web.php

```
Route::post('/upload', function (Request $request) {
    $name=$request->file("thing")->getClientOriginalName();
    Storage::disk("google")->putFileAs("",$request->file("thing"),$name);
    $url=Storage::disk('google')->url($name);
    DB::insert('insert into books (Title, Url) values (?,?)', [$name,$url]);
    
    dd('uploaded');
})->name("upload");
```

I want to save the thumbnail in database. How can I get the thumbnail. I searched but couldn't found any method.

If I get the URL of google drive file and then in normal library.php file write code which get files and mata data, will I have to connect to google drive API again or doing this in laravel project will be enough?

I have library.php in which laravel project appears on button click where I upload files.

If there is no way of getting thumbnail in laravel then can anyone please tell the code for php. I tried a lot but could not found or found some example in stakeoverflow but I don't know where to implement those get function of drive API in php file.

```
listFiles: function (folderId, onData, onError) {

    drive.files.get({
    auth: jwtClient,
    fileId: fileId,
    fields : "thumbnailLink"
})
```

example code which I found but I don't know where to right this or in library.php, am I needed to connect to API and how.

i searched a lot but could not found any thing, please help.

Comment: Can I ask you about my understanding of your question? You want to download a thumbnail of a file uploaded in Google Drive. In your situation, you have already known the file ID of the file. You want to retrieve the file metadata of the file on Google Drive using googleapis for PHP. Is my understanding correct? By the way, what is the lower script in your question?

Comment: Yes you a right, lower script is actually when I searched for the method I got this solution but I don't know how to implement this
 If you know the solution please help

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `lower script is actually when I searched for the method I got this solution`, I cannot still understand about the script. I apologize for this. But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort u r making. That script is from this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013552/google-drive-api-get-thumbnail

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your replying, It seems that the bottom script in your question is for Node.js. And, the service account is used. In that case, you want to convert the script of Node.js to PHP? Or, you want to download the thumbnail image using Node.js using the service account?

Comment: Uppps sorry I thought that was php, I can't use nodejs as I don't know how I will integrate that in my PHP application. Is there any PHP method, or even if I could just extract first page of pdf by passing drive URL, that would do my work

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your question. I apologize for this again. By the way, what is `drive URL`?

Comment: I have a database in which I store the URL of the files that are present in google drive. Now, I want the thumbnail of the files (pdf and doc). I think there are two solutions. 1. get thumbnail in PHP using google drive API, but I could not find the code to do this. 2. extract first page of the pdf or doc file whatever it is using PHP or javascript or jquery. I don't have files (pdf and doc) on my local computer but in the google drive so I can only pass the link to the file in whatever method I use. like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YVTIGaAvnzH5vF_B1t8-bKsW2Q8ymZBy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. From your replying, I understood that your `drive URL` is the URL of the file on Google Drive. Is my understanding correct? About `1. get thumbnail in PHP using google drive API, but I could not find the code to do this.`, I think that this can be achieved using PHP. If my understanding is correct, in your current situation, you want to achieve your goal using googleapis for PHP or others?

Comment: And, you have already done the authorization process and you can use the Drive API with your access token. Is my understanding correct? About `2. extract first page of the pdf or doc file whatever it is using PHP or javascript or jquery.`, you want to retrieve the thumbnail image data from the PDF and Google Document? on Google Drive. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes you r right

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script for googleapis of PHP as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. In this case, I'm worry that my answer might not be useful for your situation. So, I would like to delete my answer. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to think of the solution. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: U shouldn't have deleted the answer, i would have found a connection way

Comment: I found a connection way, I don't know how to thank you. You should repost ur answer so I can select it as best answer. You are seriously awesome and best person out here. Thanks a lot, thank you so much, it means a lot, thank you thank you

Comment: Can you please help me with one more thing, it saves the image in my computer, how can I save it directly to MySQL database

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your question, I could understand that my understanding of your question was correct. So I reopened my answer. And, about your new question, can you post it as new question? Because your new question is different from your this question. By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your current issue and your goal as follows.

- Your `drive URL` is the URL of the file on Google Drive.
- You want to download the thumbnail image data from the file (the PDF and Google Document) on Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for PHP.
- You have already done the authorization process and you can use the Drive API with your access token.

From your URL of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YVTIGaAvnzH5vF_B1t8-bKsW2Q8ymZBy/view?usp=sharing`, in this case, the file ID is `1YVTIGaAvnzH5vF_B1t8-bKsW2Q8ymZBy`. I think that this can be used for achieving your goal. When this is reflected to a sample script for googleapis of PHP, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // Please use your "$client".
$fileId = '1YVTIGaAvnzH5vF_B1t8-bKsW2Q8ymZBy'; // This is the file ID from your sample URL.

$res = $service->files->get($fileId, ["fields" => "name,thumbnailLink"]);
$thumbnailLink = str_replace('=s220', '=s1000', $res->getThumbnailLink());
$name = $res->getName();
file_put_contents($name . '.png', file_get_contents($thumbnailLink));
```

- When you run this script, the thumbnail link is retrieved from the file ID of the file in Google Drive, and the image size is changed, and then, the thumbnail image data is downloaded and create it as a file. In the current stage, it is not required to use the access token for downloading the thumbnail image data.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that your `$client` can be used for retrieving the file metadata of the file on Google Drive. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: Thank you so much for all this effort but actually I am still unable to understand. Can you explain me one thing. I have a folder "example-app" which has laravel project in which I connected to google drive api. There is another folder "webproj" in which I want to use the code which you told. So now in "webproj" how do I connect to the drive api. Like i know first we have to run command `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` but after that what do I have to include in php file to make this code work. Right now it says "Google_Service_Drive" not present

Comment: Means how to include googleservicedrive.php, where will be this file and Google client.php.   I am sorry but I am new to this and the documentation does not explain very well

Comment: @SA Ira Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. In this case, I'm worry that my answer might not be useful for your situation. So, I would like to delete my answer. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to think of the solution. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.