# How to Report Errors in Discovery V3 Specification - required parameters missing on drive.about.get

Tags: google-drive-api

drive.about.get is described by 
 the  [revision 20181101 discovery document](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest) in which the endpoint for drive:v3.about.get does not include the standard parameters included in the [API EXplorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get).

V3 is listed as the preferred version.

Given that the fields parameter is required and expects a keyed value from [The returned 'about' resource description](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about#resource) I expect that this is an erroneous omission from the discovery specification.

Although it is simple enough to work around this, for me it requires additional documentation to explain the requirement.

I note that this is the first Drive endpoint I have explored - I expect that as I continue I will see more missing required parameter specifications. Perhaps this part of the Google Discovery API schema is optional?

My question is - what is the process to help correct this? How frequently are the discovery specs updated and is it up the the user to monitor these changes.

As an additional note for users - you can provide a fields query parameter value of '*' to return all fields. This has also been touched on in [Revisions list and get missing information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958371/revisions-list-and-get-missing-information?rq=1)

Any guidance welcome.

Comment: For any bugs or issues related to the API or incomplete documents try reaching out to their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=823909) same goes for their feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Mr.Rebot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5995040/mr-rebot) for the link to [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=823909) which is the most valuable part of my objective to find an appropriate channel to pursue Discovery Specification inconsistencies.

The Google Developer API sites haven't led me there and there are quite a few minor quirks in the API Discovery docs I'd like to pursue.